# Pronunciation of "diplomatie"?

Tags: prononciation, orthographe

I heard it pronounced as if it were "diplomacie" on the radio, and then I checked it in a few places online and they all pronounced it like that as well. Why is the *t* being pronounced as a *c*? Is *-atie* always pronounced like that?

Comment: How do you pronounce *martian*? ;-)

Comment: So is that to say *-tia* is always pronounced as *-cia*? I wouldn't have assumed it was la même chose en français qu'en anglais.

Comment: Wow, plus 1 for "making me look" (it up)!  I really thought you'd spelled it wrong and I was itching for those 2 points for editing (never mind that there would have been no need for the question in that case).  I guess I've never seen it written before, except in my own, misspelled way.  Regardless, I have always assumed that it was spelled like it is pronounced, with a "c," so thanks again for helping me get a little less ignorant tonight!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the list where the suffix *-tie* is pronounced /si/. It's not so uncommon.

> acrobatie,
>   argutie,
>   aristocratie,
>   autocratie,
>   balbutie,
>   bureaucratie,
>   calvitie,
>   canitie,
>   chiropractie (*or* -axie),
>   **diplomatie**,
>   démocratie,
>   facétie,
>   gérontocratie,
>   hématie,
>   idiotie,
>   ineptie,
>   inertie,
>   initie,
>   minutie,
>   médiocratie,
>   méritocratie,
>   orthodontie,
>   phallocratie,
>   physiocratie,
>   ploutocratie,
>   presbytie,
>   primatie,
>   procuratie,
>   prophétie,
>   péripétie,
>   spermatie,
>   suprématie,
>   technocratie,
>   théocratie,
>   transsubstantie,
>   vaillantie.

Just like *-tion* or *-tien*, this suffix comes from the latin *-tiō* and is also pronounced with an /s/.

And here is a list where *-tie* happens to be pronounced /ti/.

> aboutie,
>   abrutie,
>   abêtie,
>   agalactie,
>   alentie,
>   amatie,
>   amnistie,
>   amortie,
>   anaplastie,
>   anéantie,
>   aplatie,
>   appesantie,
>   appointie,
>   apprentie,
>   assortie,
>   assujettie,
>   autoplastie,
>   avertie,
>   bipartie,
>   blottie,
>   bâtie,
>   châtie,
>   compatie,
>   consentie,
>   contrepartie,
>   convertie,
>   cotie,
>   dessertie,
>   divertie,
>   dynastie,
>   débâtie,
>   décatie,
>   déglutie,
>   démentie,
>   dénantie,
>   départie,
>   désassortie,
>   désinvestie,
>   emboutie,
>   empuantie,
>   engloutie,
>   enzootie,
>   eucharistie,
>   extravertie,
>   galvanoplastie,
>   garantie,
>   gynécomastie,
>   hostie,
>   iconoclastie,
>   immodestie,
>   impartie,
>   impéritie,
>   intervertie,
>   introvertie,
>   invertie,
>   investie,
>   kalicytie (?),
>   lotie,
>   marchantie (?),
>   matie,
>   modestie,
>   moitie,
>   nantie,
>   néottie (?),
>   ortie,
>   ostéoplastie,
>   palmipartie,
>   partie,
>   pervertie,
>   plastie,
>   pressentie,
>   pâtie,
>   pédérastie,
>   quadripartie,
>   ralentie,
>   raplatie,
>   rapointie,
>   rassortie,
>   rebâtie,
>   reconvertie,
>   repartie,
>   repentie,
>   ressentie,
>   ressortie,
>   rhinoplastie,
>   roustie,
>   réassortie,
>   réinvestie,
>   répartie,
>   rôtie,
>   sacristie,
>   scotie,
>   sentie,
>   sertie,
>   sortie,
>   stomatoplastie,
>   subvertie,
>   thoracoplastie,
>   travestie,
>   tripartie,
>   uranoplastie,
>   écatie,
>   épiphytie,
>   épizootie,
>   époutie.

Many are simply past participles from *-ir* verbs. Others kept the original /t/ from the greek.

Answering your last question, notice that *amatie*, *aplatie*, *décatie*, *matie*, *raplatie*, *écatie*, among which *aplatie* and *raplatie* are the only common words, end in *-atie* but are pronounced /ti/.

Answer (score 3):

- **FR**: /di.plɔ.ma.si/
- **EN**: /dɪˈpləʊ.mə.si/

**-atie** is usually — but not always — pronounced /asi/.

Comment: Quelques exceptions: aplatie, décatie, voire compatie, châtie et bâtie.

Comment: @jlliagre, toutes les exceptions semblent être dérivées de verbes (aplatir, décatir, châtier, bâtir) Quelqu'un connait-il d'autres cas?  (En passant, _compatir_ est intransitif, et donc _compatie_ me semble mal formé).

Comment: @Unfrancophone J'ai mis « voire compatie » car ce participe passé me semble en effet très douteux. Les seules occurrences que j'ai trouvées en dehors de certaines tables de conjugaison sont des « Je compatie » très incorrects.